# Unable to display virtual machines sizes

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

Our Azure portal is showing an odd error to one of our contributors.
When he tries to create a new Virtual Machine, he can input the basic settings.
But once he gets to the part where he is supposed to define the virtual machine sizes, he gets the message `Unable to display virtual machines sizes`.

And this no matter the type of virtual machine he tries to create.

I've created a support ticket with Azure, however in the meantime, has anyone seen this error before and know how to resolve it?

Comment: I have the same problem. But still no solution.
I think it's a permission issue.
But what kind of permission need to be added to user?
My user has "Contributor" role on a Resource group.

Comment: Already tried giving the user Owner permissions, which didn't solve it.

Comment: @Aland17: Please read our [help] to learn how the site works. "Me too" answers or comments are not welcome at all unless they actually contribute to finding a solution.

Comment: @Aland17 Found the solution... sort off. Hope it helped you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by Microsoft support, and we received the root cause analysis a week later.

Apparently the day before, a new version of the API was released.
Microsoft ended up rolling back the portal API, which solved the issue for us, and several other customers.

So in our case, this was not a solve-able problem, the only recourse was to contact Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

You might be missing the required resource provider.  When provisioning resources via the portal, it should add the appropriate provider to your account, however, that doesn't always happen.

See [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-supported-services/) for more information on Azure resource providers.

I suspect you are missing key resource providers such as Microsoft.Compute.

Try running `Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable` to see which ones are registered for you.

Comment: This  isn't it. As I mentioned it happens no matter the virtual machine chosen, and only for this user. M$ support was able to resolve it and once I get the full details I'll post them as an answer.